# Angular filter by if checked / by classname?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I'm am learning Angular right now and working on a project for class that has a finite list of bucket list tasks to display and several ways to filter them based on how my data is organized. (e.g. by price level, etc.)

I'd like to have it so that a user can mark an item as done/not done and then filter by which tasks are done/not done. I have been trying to do this with checkboxes (if checked/not checked) or by adding a class (which has been trickier than I thought...).

(*Also, to clarify, I do not want to check a box to filter the data on the page, which I know is a pretty common way to implement Angular filters? I want the filter to return only divs that have their checkbox checked.)*

Currently, here are each of my filter buttons are set up:

`<button id="free" data-ng-click="itemFilter={free: true}">Free</button>`

Where my data then has:

`<li class="each-item" data-ng-repeat="item in ItemIndexViewModel.items | orderBy:'name' | filter:itemFilter">`

I currently have the checkboxes set to change the color of the text, but I guess I don't know what I should then be filtering by: the color, the checked box, or an added class if I'm able to get a toggled class name in there (which, so far, I have not.)

Would love some insight as to how best to do this and what Angular filters are capable of doing?

Comment: You are thinking about it all wrong...you would filter by the property of each data object that the checkbox is bound to. See the classic http://todomvc.com/ for example code

Comment: @charlietfl: I understand that you can filter by data properties, that's what the "free" property is: a Boolean value in the data. But is that the only way I can filter?

Answer (score 0):

You're close.. the button should look more like this `<button id="free" data-ng-click="itemFilter = true">Show Free = true</button>`. Then your ng-repeat should look like this `<li class="each-item" data-ng-repeat="item in ItemIndexViewModel.items | orderBy:'name' | filter: {free: itemFilter}">`. Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/u2Xja9pkVBY2kA8SeGtt).